# How to update each and every keys of redux state by iteration with immutable principle

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a redux state as follows:-

```
data = {"facebook":true,"twitter":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"watsapp":false}
```

I will be passing the key values in action ex:-("facebook","twitter")

lets say i passed "facebook".
Then I want the state to be updated to

```
{"facebook":true,"twitter":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"watsapp":false}
```

here is my reducer function

```
function data = (state=initialstate,action) => {
   return {...state, [action.account]=true}
}
```

For first time, it will give desired result.

```
{"facebook":true,"twitter":false,"google":false,"instagram":false,"watsapp":false}
```

Now lets say, I am passing the key "twitter"

What I want:

```
{"facebook":false,"twitter":true,"google":false,"instagram":false,"watsapp":false}
```

What I was getting with above reducer function (as expected)

```
{"facebook":true,"twitter":true,"google":false,"instagram":false,"watsapp":false}
```

So I updated my reducer function to as following:-

```
function data = (state, action) => {
  Object.keys(state).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key!=action.account){
      state[key]=false; 
    } else {
      state[key]=true; 
    }
   });
  return state
}
```

But this is against redux principle of immutable data.
As I am using selector as well, it is showing some unexpected behaviour.

How to update my reducer function which will set all the previously set values to **false** and will only set the current key to **true** keeping in mind immutable data principle of redux

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you would like all keys to be set to `false`, with the exception of the dispatched `action.account` to be set to `true`.

```
const data = (state, action) => {
    let { account } = action
    var newObj = {}

    Object.keys(state).forEach(function(key) {
        newObj[key] = false
    })

    return {...newObj, [account]:true }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check Tharaka Wijebandara's answer and let me know which is the preferred way.. I mean is there any best practise to follow your's suggestion or the above solution

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/),<sup>*</sup> you could use `_.map(state, (v, k) => /* logic that returns true/false */)` to produce a new `state` instance, whilst leaving the previous one untouched.

Note that it feels like a better data model may simply be to store a single string in your state, corresponding to the "current" account.

---

<sub>* Equivalent behaviour is achievable using `Object.entries()....`, but it's gross and I don't want to figure it out :)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Simply, use a new empty object instead of modifying the original state object.

```
function data = (state, action) => {
  const newState = {};
  Object.keys(state).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key!=action.account){
      newState[key]=false; 
    } else {
      newState[key]=true; 
    }
   });
  return newState
}
```

Comment: haha..seriously..I thought of doing it using newstate but thought it is not redux way. Anywayz, can you please check meteorBuzz's answer and let me know which one is preferred way.

Comment: As longs as you create new state without mutating previous state it's acceptable in Redux. Also I don't see any significant difference in two answers. Both will do the job. Use whatever the method make more sense to you.

Comment: Careful, always use `!==` instead of `!=` of could have unpleasant results!